# I am not sure if my Vue code is efficient

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am a beginner in Vue and I am wondering if I can get an insight from experienced developers here about my Vue codes. I just want to ask for help to know if my Vue approach is efficient and proper. (Project is running on Laravel)

---

### The Case:

Let us say I have 2 tables in DB

> (1) stores
>
> (2) ad_accounts

Then we have 2 web pages to present these tables' data and execute CRUD functions with it

> (1) store.blade.php
>
> (2) adaccount.blade.php

Each page is running a Vue component

> (1) Stores.vue
>
> (2) AdAccounts.vue

I am using **Vuex** for store management.

Within **store.js**, I would have set of **actions** for CRUD for each vue component.

Now I realized that I have series of actions that actually does the same thing. For example, I have an action to add stores, and another action to add Ad accounts. Their only difference is that they are calling a different Laravel route.

So it seemed to me that my code was unnecessarily long and a bit expensive. To resolve, I decided to write my actions in a form of template. So this is what I did:

1. In store.js, I created an ***action for each CRUD function*** to be used as ***template***
2. In Stores.vue and AdAccounts.vue, if I need to execute a CRUD function, I would use a ***method to call the corresponding action*** from store.js and provide the ***Laravel route as part of the action's payload***
3. I have ***states*** and corresponding ***getters*** for returning these states in Stores.vue and AdAccounts.vue
4. Each action has a dedicated **mutation** that alters the approriate state
5. states and getters are ***mapped in each Vue component*** in order to access and use them

Is this approach efficient and proper? I have sample methods and actions below for reference.

---

**Stores.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="addData('stores/add')">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        addData: function(url) {
            this.payload.url = url
            if(
                this.payload.requestData.store_name == "" &&
                this.payload.requestData.store_token == ""
            ) {
                this.payload.isErr = true;
                this.payload.errMsg = "ERROR: Could not continue due to some invalid or missing data. \nPlease check your entries and try again or contact your administrator.";
                this.$store.dispatch('addData', this.payload)
            }
            else {
                this.payload.isErr = false;
                this.$store.dispatch('addData', this.payload)
                this.readDataAll('stores/all', 'store');
            }
            this.cleanOnModalDismiss(this.$refs.addModal, this.refreshRequestData)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**AdAccounts.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="addData('ad_accounts/add')">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        addData: function(url) {
            this.payload.url = url
            if(
                this.payload.requestData.ad_id == "" &&
                this.payload.requestData.ad_name == ""
            ) {
                this.payload.isErr = true;
                this.payload.errMsg = "ERROR: Could not continue due to some invalid or missing data. \nPlease check your entries and try again or contact your administrator.";
                this.$store.dispatch('addData', this.payload)
            }
            else {
                this.payload.isErr = false;
                this.$store.dispatch('addData', this.payload)
                this.readDataAll('ad_accounts/all', 'adaccounts');
            }
            this.cleanOnModalDismiss(this.$refs.addModal, this.refreshRequestData)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

```javascript
export default new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
        addData (commit, payload) { // insert a record to DB
            try {
                if(payload.isErr == true) {
                    commit('SHOW_ERRORS', {messageType: "alert-danger", errorMessage: payload.errMsg});
                } else {            
                    axios.post(payload.url, payload.requestData)
                    .then(response=>{
                        if(response.status == 200) {
                            var err_msg = "";
                            if(response.data.success !== null) {
                                response.data.messageType = "alert-info"
                                response.data.actionMessage = response.data.success
                                commit('ADD_DATA', response.data);
                            } else {
                                response.data.messageType = "alert-danger"
                                for(var i=0; i<response.data.error.length; i++) {
                                    err_msg += response.data.error[i] + "\n"
                                }
                                response.data.actionMessage = err_msg
                                commit('ADD_DATA', response.data);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            commit('SHOW_ERRORS', {messageType: "alert-danger", errorMessage: "ERROR: Connection status set to '" + response.headers.connection + "' due to error " + response.status + " " + response.statusText + ". \nPlease contact your administrator."});
                        }
                    })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                commit('SHOW_ERRORS', {messageType: "alert-danger", errorMessage: error})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the complexity of the application. There would nothing be wrong if you went with two Stores; one for `StoreStore`, another - `StoreAdAccount`,  each with its' own actions, mutations, getters, etc.

Comment: Oh really we can actually do that? I actually thought of this when first started using Vuex, thought it would make things easier and codes cleaner too. I tried but I don't know how to do it in Laravel so I thought maybe it's not possible at all. Maybe you could share any related article you know? Thanks!